# How to get dropdown dynamically with ul li inside ul using php?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have a `ul li` with `parentid` . I want all `ul li` with `parentid` but I'm getting multiple loops.  The first steps and last are under same `parentid`.
[image]

```
<ul class="section-list"> 
<?php   
    if(count($outArrResults)>0){    
        for($i=0; $i<count($outArrResults); $i++){
            ?>
                <li class="o-view">
                    <a href='javascript:void(0);'>
                        <h4 class="tit-section xsm">
                            <?php echo isset($outArrResults[$i]['cName']) ?$outArrResults[$i]['cName'] : '';?>
                        </h4>
                    </a>
                    <ul>
                        <?php
                            for($s=0; $s<count($outArrResults); $s++){
                                $contentSlugUrl = isset($outArrResults[$s]['conSName']) ? $outArrResults[$s]['conSName']:'';
                                $contentMenuTitle = isset($outArrResults[$s]['conMTitle']) ? $outArrResults[$s]['conMTitle']:'';
                                if($contentMenuTitle!=''){
                                    ?>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href='<?php echo $config['LIVE_URL'].'courses/'.$pAction1.'/'.$pAction2.'/'.$contentSlugUrl;?>'>
                                                <span><?php echo $contentMenuTitle;?></span>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    <?php
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            <?php
        }
    } else {
        echo "No Results";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why are you cycling twice `for($s=0; $s<count($outArrResults); $s++){`? Also, can you give us an example of the data into your array, and an example of the desired final result?

Comment: I want multiple  ul so i used it

Comment: [0] => Array
        (
            [conId] => 4
            [cId] => 14
            [cName] => first steps
            [conName] => ddd
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [conId] => 7
            [cId] => 15
            [cName] => last
            [conName] => saaas
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [conId] => 8
            [cId] => 14
            [cName] => first steps
            [conName] => ss
        )

)

Comment: Can you please clarify your question adding a) an example of the data into your array and b) the desired output? You can do this by clicking *edit* just below your question. Please read also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to write a question that is answerable and helpful also to future readers.